# EditText Remove Text Selection Context Bar Not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

Tried clearing the menu but still no way.
It dosent shows in emulator but in device with android 7 its not getting removed.

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

        et.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                menu.clear();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                menu.clear();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

            }
        });
```

[image]